Second-order phase transition of lattice gas model
Consider the lattice gas energy:
$$
H = -\epsilon \sum_{\text{n.n}}c_ic_j-\mu \sum_i c_i,
$$
where $c_i$ is the occupation at $i$ and can be $0$ (empty) or $1$ (occupied).
I am using the Monte Carlo method to try to simulate the phase transition at different temperatures. What I expect is a similar result compared to the Ising model, a first-order transition at low temperatures and a second-order transition at high temperatures.
The results I have obtained are as follows:

which seems to be ok. But when I go to higher temperatures, a stable state at $\rho=0.5$ appears. Here are some of my results:



I believe that this is not observed in the Ising model. Is this result correct? If so, what is the explanation for this stable state?
Edit: The lattice is in $2$D and I am using the metropolis algorithm. But instead of evaluating the algorithm one site at a time,  I am doing it for all sites simultaneously in each iteration. Is this causing the problem?

What's the dimension you are considering? Also, you could try to add a few more details, such as defining $\rho$, what algorithm do you use, ecc.

It is a lattice in 2D, using the metropolis algorithm. But instead of evaluating the algorithm one site at a time, I am doing it for all sites simultaneously in each iteration. I am wondering if that is causing the problem.
